# How to initiate a variable from the Grammar in Bison?

Tags: c++, parsing, bison, interpreter

let's imagine we have this grammar

```
start: 
expressions;
expressions:
           expressions expression 
           | expression 
           ;
expression:
          expression NAME value { float $2 = $3;}
          | NAME value  { float $1 = $2;}
          ;
value:
      INT '.' INT
      ;
```

and for this grammar we apply this input

a 2.0
b 3.0

this should be interpreted by our grammar like this ( float a = 2.0 ; float b = 3.0; )

my aim is really to declare some variable with a name and with a constructor do some thing like myClass NAME(value); and value is a float.

the problems are I don't know how to get the whole value of a grammatical bloc like value in my exemple and how to make a declaration of variable name that will change in each line with in input file and wont have some generic float a = $1;

I already have my flex tokeniser working which will give me NAME and VALUE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use strings in place of variable names in C++. What you should do instead is to define a map from strings to floats and then do something like `the_map[$2] = $3;` instead of `float $2 = $3;`.

On an unrelated note, you need to add an action to `value` that makes it produce a float value (or make your lexer generate a single token for floats and use that). Otherwise `$3` doesn't have a proper value when you use it in `expression`'s action.

Comment: and how to value produce a float ? like creating a new union and creat a type for value which will be a float ?

Comment: @Gengetsu To create a float out of your two integers, you could paste them together into a string with a dot in between and then use `strtod` on that string. That's assuming your lexer creates string values for INT tokens, not `int`s. If you get `int`s from the lexer, there's no way to correctly work with them (you'll lose leading 0s in the fractional part). A better alternative would probably be to just make the lexer produce a single token for floats anyway. I do not understand the second part of your comment.

Comment: ok , I see the second part of my comment is how to convert an INT ( int ) to a float which you already said it's not possible , so thanks I see what to do now

Comment: "float $2 = $3;" statement makes no sense, the variable behind $2 already exists

Comment: @SoronelHaetir I assumed that the intention behind that line was to take the string in `$2` and use that as the name of a newly defined variable, which, as I said, isn't possible in C++ (and even in languages where you can do that, I'd generally consider it a bad idea). Thus my recommendation to use a map instead.